# How to print format align a list of columns

Tags: java, printing, format, alignment

I got the first two columns but now i am having trouble aligning the rest of the columns with their headers

**What prints**

```
                 Male                       Female
Rank   Name              Number   Name              Number
   1   Christopher     52,308      Jessica   46,459
   2   Matthew     44,783       Ashley   45,548
   3   Joshua     43,203     Brittany   36,535
   4   Daniel     33,791       Amanda   34,389
   5   Nicholas     27,901     Samantha   25,862
   6   Anthony     25,070        Sarah   25,801
   7   William     24,875    Stephanie   24,850
   8   Kyle     22,695     Jennifer   22,217
   9   Jacob     21,992    Elizabeth   20,738
```

---

```
System.out.printf("%4.5s   %-3.20s     %,-9d%10.20s%,9d%n",
     rank,maleName,maleCount,femaleName,femaleCount);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The String formats you use, like `%4.5s`, `%-3.20s` and `%10.20s` do not do what you think they do.

For example, `%10.20s` says format a String, taking at least 10 characters, and at most 20 characters. This will pad short strings to 10, and truncate long strings to 20 chars.

To get consistent formatting, the numbers before, and after the `.` in String formats should be the same. So, for example, to left-justify the `maleName` and always take exaactly 20 characters no matter how long the name, then use `%-20.20s`

Answer (score 0):

First, give a constant larger for the column. For example for the colum 'name',

```
int columnLength = 15;
```

Before you print 'name', calculate the difference between the *columnLength* and the number of character of the name, let's call it nbSpace,

```
int nbSpace = columnLength - name.length;
String space = "";

for(int i = 0; i < nbSpace; i++) {
    space += " ";
}
```

Then, fill by space

```
System.out.print(name+space);
```